Do Python packages have to be built in the same environment as the project (source) files?
I am working through the official Python Packaging Tutorial. I use conda environments, but the question should be the same for venv virtual environments.
The tutorial presents a very simple example package with one module and no dependencies. The module contains a function which merely adds one to the passed number:
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1

I created a new module which mimics add_one, except it uses NumPy to add an array of ones to the passed array:
import numpy as np

def add_ones(array):
    return array + np.ones(array.shape)

I then created a conda environment called packaging and installed build and twine. I was able to successfully package the example package using two build backends (Hatchling and Flit). I was also able upload the package to TestPyPI. I was then able to pip install the package from PyPI. If I install it to an environment that is missing NumPy, the import of course fails, but so long as I install it to an environment that does have NumPy, the import works and the function runs successfully.
My question is whether this behavior is reliable? For this simple example, build works from an environment that is missing the package's dependencies, such as my packaging environment which is missing NumPy.

Your package structure has to include a setup.py file, or, preferably, a pyproject.toml file with a PEP 517 compliant build-backend. There, you need to add a dependencies table that declares NumPy as a dependency for your project.
This shall ensure that those who receive your built package from an index also receive this metadata along with it, and therefore receive a distribution/wheel of NumPy for use by your package. To answer your question in specific, this behaviour is not reliable at this time without an explicit declaration of the dependencies of your project.
The PyPA's build build frontend prepares a source distribution and a wheel (this is customisable) for your project and does not need to "import" your project per se (unless you have a more complicated build procedure that involves setuptools or other compilation steps). It is possible to build and distribute distribution formats for a Python project without having included the dependencies required to import/run it.
It might also make sense to distribute an environment.yml file in your source code containing a list of necessary dependencies, and document the procedure for users as to how to use it to create reproducible conda environments.


For this simple example, build works from an environment that is missing the package's dependencies, such as my packaging environment which is missing NumPy.

Because building/packaging usually doesn't require running any code from the project, the requirements to build or package a project usually don't require many, if any, of the package's runtime requirements. In the most basic sense, 'building' a package is basically just zipping up your source files.
Your package metadata (for example, as declared in setup.py/setup.cfg/pyproject.toml or similar) should specify your runtime requirements, such as numpy, so that it is installed if not present when users request your package to be installed. That way, your package should always in a working state after it is installed by a package manager like pip.
In the conda world, there are some additional ways to describe your dependencies and other metadata. For example, with conda-build and recipes and meta.yaml specification, among other ways to describe metadata of conda packages.
